Fourier transform and antiderivative
Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{C}$ is $m$ times continuously differentiable and compactly supported. Then for $\mu=(\mu_1,\dots,\mu_d)\in\mathbb{N}_0^d$ with $|\mu|=\mu_1+\dots+\mu_d\le m$, we know the Fourier transform of the partial derivative $\frac{\partial^\mu f}{\partial x^\mu}$ is
$$\mathcal{F}\left[\frac{\partial^\mu f}{\partial x^\mu}\right](\xi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\frac{\partial^\mu f}{\partial x^\mu}(x)e^{-ix\cdot\xi}\,dx=(-i\xi)^\mu \mathcal{F}f(\xi),\quad\xi\in\mathbb{R}^d.$$
Moreover, the Paley-Wiener theorem says that $\mathcal{F}\left[\frac{\partial^\mu f}{\partial x^\mu}\right]$ and $\mathcal{F}f$ are both analytic functions.
I am interested in whether the Fourier transform has an anti-derivative analog. To be specific, suppose $\eta:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{C}$ is a compactly supported and continuous function such that its Fourier transform $\mathcal{F}\eta$ satisfies
$$\lim_{\xi\to 0}\frac{\mathcal{F}\eta(\xi)}{(-i\xi)^\alpha}=L$$
for some $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_d)\in\mathbb{N}_0^d$ and $L\in\mathbb{C}$. Define $$\phi(\xi):=\begin{cases}\frac{\mathcal{F}\eta(\xi)}{(-i\xi)^\alpha}, &\xi\neq 0,\\
L, &\xi=0.\end{cases}.$$
My questions: Is it necessary that $\phi$ is the Fourier transform of some compactly supported function (distribution) $f$, and $\frac{\partial^\alpha f}{\partial x^\alpha}=\eta$?
If not, what additional assumptions on $\eta$ are needed to make this claim true?
Intuitively, I think the answer should be positive. However, when I try to write down the proof formally, I have some trouble. By the definition of $\phi$, it is clear that $\phi$ is analytic. However, to apply the Paley-Wiener theorem, there are restrictions on the growth of $|\phi(\xi)|$ as $|\xi|$ gets large, and this is where the problem arises. Any suggestions are welcomed. Thanks!

The function $\phi$ you constructed is also analytic, and actually extendable to an entire function. You also have that $\phi$ is bounded for (complex) $|z|\leq 1$, and $|\phi(z)|\leq |\mathcal F\eta(z)|\leq (1+|z|)^{-N}C_N\cdot \exp(B,\Im(z))$ for $|z|>1$. The last inequality comes from Schwarz-Paley-Wiener theorem, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Wiener_theorem#Schwartz's_Paley%E2%80%93Wiener_theorem . By the same theorem, it follows that also the (anti-)Fourier transform of $\phi$ is smooth and compactly supported. The fact that $\partial^\alpha f=\eta$ is standard

@LorenzoPompili, I see. The trick is to work with different cases $|z|\leq 1$ and $|z|>1$. Thanks for the answer.
